# Server and Network Lag

Tags: networking, lag

At my home I have a server and my computer. Server has Windows Server 2008 Standart 64 bit installed and then my computer has Windows 7 64 bit installed. My home router is DIR-615

My server has a game server installed on it and basically total open connections on server are around 700. Once its around 700 server and then whole home network lags really badly.

My internet connection is good and only around 600kb/s is being used out of 2mb/s (real download/upload speeds).

So far I assume that my router has a connection limit and with server + my computer connections it peaks at around 1k and lags everything. Another assumption server lag comes from connection limit. On the internet I have read that standart version of server has connection limit of 700 + 10 reserved. I do not rmember where I found that information but it was on microsoft website.

So I have two options. First is to upgrade my router to Netgear FVS318G-100 and second is to change connections limit on server.

Any advices?

Thank you

Comment: Can you fix the capitalization of your units so we know what actual values you are talking about and don't have to guess?

Comment: How come you have $2k of server software but are running it on a $40 router? I'm not surprised you're having problems doing what you are, especially over a regular broadband link.

Comment: Probably better on superuser.com (people will have more experience with the consumer routers)

Comment: Well I am thinking about getting better router like that netgear. Running server over that broadband is ok and more than enough. I think I will get that netgear. Also how can i increase connection limit from 700 to 1400 or more?